# quantification of glucose utilization in different metabolic processes

Tags: metabolism, literature, glucose

Glucose is commonly associated with ATP production. However, only a small fraction of glucose is utilized this way.

The intermediates of glycolysis, TCA cycle, etc. are precursors to various anabolic pathways and are ultimately involved in amino acid synthesis, nucleotide synthesis, fatty acid synthesis, etc.

Has glucose utilization in different pathways been quantified? What approximate percentage of glucose is used in different pathways?

Certainly, the numbers could vary between organisms, different cell types, cell microenvironment, etc. It helps to have an intuition of how much glucose is used where.

Comment: A general answer to this question is not possible because of the difference in organisms and cell types mentioned. However there are some more basic problems with the question. 1. Where is the glucose coming from? Assuming even a single organism such as man, there are a variety of possible diets. 2. The extent of synthesis depends on the nutritional state of the animal and whether cells are dividing. 3. In the paragraph "Has glucose utilization…", the second sentence is incomplete and meaning of the first sentence is unclear.

Comment: My question originated while reading a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41580-019-0123-5) which claimed that only a small fraction of glucose eventually ends up undergoing oxidative phosphorylation. Most of the intermediates of the glycolysis and TCA cycle are precursors for biosynthesis of amino acids, nucleotides, etc. I naturally wondered how much of glucose is used where to garner an intuition.

Comment: Well give us the reference. Then we can see what the system is.